# Choose method depending on configurations array

Tags: php

So I have the following import records method (**I've removed the unneeded parts from the method**):

```
private function import_records(array $config = []): array
{
    // Loop through all Octopus records
    foreach ($result->data as $record) {
        if ($config['settings_key'] === 'import_profiles') {
            $this->sync_profile($record);
        } else if ($config['settings_key'] === 'import_offices') {
            $this->sync_office($record);
        }
    }

    return $config;
}
```

Then I'm calling it as such:

```
public function import_offices(): array
{
    return $this->import_records([
        'settings_key' => 'import_offices',
        'path' => 'offices',
    ]);
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to call the `sync_profile` and `sync_office` methods in the if statement, than having to hardcode the `$config['settings_key'] === 'string'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call function using string in php

```
foreach ($result->data as $record) {
    $this->{$config["settings_key"]}($record);
}
```

then your `$config` will look like this

```
return $this->import_records([
        'settings_key' => 'sync_office', // change this to your method name
        'path' => 'offices',
]);
```

[source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)